# Using Derivative of Sigmoid in Backpropagation will cause the errors to be zero? - Neural Networks

Tags: java, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm coding a Neural Network using Error Backpropagation. For this, I have to determine the error of the previous layer from the error of the next layer. I'm no expert, but from what I've seen, using the following formula is the (or one) correct way of doing this:

```
error = ( Weights_next^T * error_next ) .* sigmoid_Derivative(net)
```

What confuses me about this is the usage of the Derivative of the Sigmoid function. It kinda does make sense to use it, but since the Derivative of the Sigmoid is always smaller or equal to 0.25, this means that moving backwards from layer to layer, the error will decrease exponentially. This will then result in almost no weight adjustments in any but the last layer.

Sadly, this is exactly what happens in my NN right now, with the last Layer having some valid error, but all the others just having an error of 0.

Isn't it necessary to adjust this formula by a factor of 4, so that the highest factor is not 0.25 anymore, but 1.0 instead?

Or am I doing something else wrong here?

Comment: Training a model normally involves a huge amount of runs. When you say, the errors mostly do not propagate to the previous levels, it is an observation for one individual run only, assume. But is it still a problem after a few thousand runs? Ideally, the training algorithm should eventually adjust all weights.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen The algorithm works perfectly if there is only one hidden layer. But as soon as I add more than one, it doesn't work at all since all the weights of the front layers will not change. Even if I run 10,000 inputs, they stay the same. I checked my Code for bugs, but don't seem to be able to find any. Nore sure what the issue is.